# Ruby, how use in a Proc a variable that is defined in a latter stage

Tags: ruby, proc

Im my real code I have bunch or Procs that need access to multiple out-of-the-proc variables. It will be very helpful for me if I have not to take care in which order the variables and procs are defined, as far they are defined in the moment the Proc is executed.

For example:

```rb
my_proc = Proc.new { puts name }
name = "Jacinto"
my_proc.call # => undefined local variable or method `name' for main:Object (NameError)
```

This works:

```rb
name = "Jacinto"
my_proc = Proc.new { puts name }
my_proc.call # => Jacinto
```

This also works:

```rb
name = nil
my_proc = Proc.new { puts name }
name = "Jacinto"
my_proc.call # => Jacinto
```

But as I said for code readability and comfortability I want to be able to define the Proc before the variable is defined. How can I solve this?

(In my mind this should be totally possible since the code in the Proc has a delayed execution and when the execution is triggered the variable is there. )

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a parameter:

```
my_proc = Proc.new { |name| puts name }
name = "Jacinto"
my_proc.call(name) # => "Jacinto"
```